# adding 'Line break' after every 100th comma in shell

Tags: shell

I have string like
6160240,6160549,6160624,6158160,20560188,19866970,19807514,19685813,19682233,20455845,20595203,20601402,21508503,32956758,34081914,34386173,34265196,34263319,34265385,34263522,36630336,36630589,36630591,36630838,36630959,37664656,36631440,36631648,36632150,36632179,36632275,36632314,36632536,36632706,36632861,36633136,36633306,37737508,36633486,36634058,37738241,36634693,36634831,36635139,36635372,35149876,35149904,36635608,36636103,36636243,36636361,36636768,36636907,36637715,36637640,36637714,37736980,36637826,36637812,36637861,36638090,36638134,36638234,36638295,36638359,34547094,36638485,36638505,36638498,36638530,36638677,36638785,36638914,36639087,36639202,36639495,36639653,36639769,36640190,36170078,36640708,36641054,36641301,36641432,36641716,36642092,36642256,36643036,36643014,36643079,36643175,36643332,36643278,36643464,36643450,36643540,36643599,36644403,36203443,36203691,36628420,34604940,35150233,35150559,35150773,36632645,36632832,36632994,36632999,36633390,35184365,36633526,36633737,36633863,36634170,36634337,36764568,36634512,36634749,36634943,36635187,36635488,36635487,36635525,36635718,36635774,36635808,36637339,36637227,36637372,36637505,36637524,36637628,36638599,36639250,36639368,36644264,35173346,35173601,35173852,35174063,35174319,36079290,36500810,35150932,35151905,35149995,36631119,36631145,35150034,35150073,36631270,36631672,36631720,37665226,36473592,37747510,37747650,36202448,36202552,35149848,35149931,35174556,35174806,35174999,35175206,35175393,35175610,35175802,35176004,35176273,35176474,35176644,35176880,35177109,35177302,35177585,35177832,35150358,35150369,35178014,35178201,35178364,35179059,35179272,35179474,35179678,35179870,35180431,35181848,35218576,35150938,35151381,35151491,35151654,37661700,37736868,37737181,37662158,37738000,37663184,36486101,36641050,36641048,36641182,36641203,36641327,36641346,36641529,36642933,36628764,36630109,36630669,36630810,36631308,36631378,36631447,36631581,36631875,36631901,36632043,36632400,36632460,36634340,36634422,36628850,36629036,36634559,36636898,36637032,36637091,36637225,36637272,36629108,37658466,36690734,36637898,36637935,36637893,36638039,36638038,36638056,36638160,36638203,36639077,36639691,36639940,36639976,36640013,36640088,36640130,36630423,36630485,36635337,36640276,36640374,36640634,36640728,36640856,36640917,36641514,36641501,36478321,36635507,36635638,36635869,36635944,36635994,36636106,36636648,36636600,37660725,36641906,36643702,36643722,36643864,36643930,36644083,36636806,36636949,36637145,36637593,37662713,37663978,36638303,36638337,36638401,36638380,36638424,36638620,36638660,36638746,36638737,36638791,36638792,36638955,36638971,36638954,36639065,36639049,37664942,36639312,36639429,36639514,36639553,36639665,36639807,36640216,36640540,37666555,37420783,36630174,37300773,37659514,37662371,37737330,37737820,37738149,37776585,36202193,36202681,36202791,35173019,35181805,35151181,35151274,35151501,35151573,35152487

i want to add line break after every 100th comma, i need to shorten this line to bring this string into sqlplus.

Answer (score 1):

```
tr ',' '\n' <infile |paste -sd $(printf '%.1s' ,{1..99})',\n'
```

via https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/446401